# Signalr 2 disconnects on method to ListAll in table, but can insert into table with Create method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Okay, so let me start off by putting the code here so you can read what it is all about while I try to explain what goes wrong.

This is my **SignalR Hub** as you can see.

```
 namespace talkbooks.Hubs
{
    public class DiscussionHub : Hub
    {
        ApplicationDbContext _ctx;

        public DiscussionHub()
        {
            _ctx = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _ctx.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        public void Create(string title)
        {
            var discussion = _ctx.InsertDiscussion(title);

            Clients.All.DiscussionCreated(discussion);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Discussion> GetAll()
        {
            var all = _ctx.Discussions.ToArray();
            return all;
        }
        public void Hello()
        {
            Clients.All.hello();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the **database context**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Discussion> Discussions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }

    public Discussion InsertDiscussion(string title)
    {


        var discussion = new Discussion
        {
            Title = title
        };

        Discussions.Add(discussion);
        SaveChanges();

        return discussion;
    }

    public Message InsertMessage(string content, Discussion discussion)
    {

        ApplicationUser user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
        var message = new Message
        {
            MessageContent = content,
            Discussion = discussion,
            User = user
        };
        Messages.Add(message);
        SaveChanges();
        return message;
    }
}
```

The **Javascript**

```
    function expandTemplateWithData(templateName, data) {
        var template = document.getElementById(templateName);
        if (template == null) return; document.createElement("span");
        var templateString = template.innerHTML;

        for (var property in data) {
            templateString = templateString.split("%" + property + "%").join(data[property]);
        }
        return $(templateString)[0];
    }
    function addOrReplaceRow(discussion) {
    var tableBody = document.getElementById("discussionTableBody");
    var row = expandTemplateWithData("discussionRowTemplate", discussion);

    row.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        document.location = "/Discussion/Details/" + discussion.ID;
    });

    var $existingRow = $("[data-thread='" + discussion.ID + "']");
    if ($existingRow.length == 1) {
        tableBody.replaceChild(row, $existingRow[0]);
    } else {
        tableBody.appendChild(row);
    }
}


$(function () {
    $.connection.hub.logging = true;
    var discussionHub = $.connection.discussionHub;
    var button = document.getElementById("saveDiscussionButton");
    var title = document.getElementById("title");

    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        discussionHub.server.create(title.value).done(function () {
            title.value = "";
        })
    })

    discussionHub.client.discussionUpdated =
        discussionHub.client.discussionCreated = function (discussion) {
            addOrReplaceRow(discussion);
        };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        discussionHub.server.getAll().done(function (discussions) {
            discussions.forEach(discussionHub.client.discussionUpdated);
        });
    });
});
```

And finally, **the View**

```
    <h2>Index</h2>

<script id="discussionRowTemplate" type="text/html">
    <tr data-thread="%ID%">
        <td>%Title%</td>
    </tr>
</script>
<button id="newDiscussionButton" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createDiscussionModal">New Discussion</button> <hr /> 
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed  table-hover"> 
    <discussion> 
        <tr>   
            <th>Title</th>
        </tr> 
    </discussion> 
    <tbody id="discussionTableBody"></tbody> 
</table>

<div id="createDiscussionModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">                
            <button type="button" class="close" data- dismiss="modal">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
            </button>                
            <h4 class="modal-title">New discussion</h4>            
            </div>            
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">                        
                    <label for="title">Title</label>                        
                    <input id="title" type="text" class="form- control" placeholder="Enter title">                   
                    </div>                    
                </form>
            </div>                        
            <div class="modal-footer">                
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>                
                <button id="saveDiscussionButton" type="button" data- dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Discussion/Index.js"></script>
}
```

So what is the problem? I am trying to use the GetAll() method to return an array and fill the table in the Index, but it isn't working. Viewing the Developers Console gives this:

```
SignalR: Invoking discussionhub.GetAll.jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js (9,3266)
SignalR: Websocket closed.jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js (9,3266)
    SignalR: Closing the Websocket.jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js (9,3266)
    SignalR: Clearing hub invocation callbacks with error: Connection started reconnecting before invocation result was received..jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js (9,3266)
    SignalR: discussionhub.GetAll failed to execute. Error: Connection started reconnecting before invocation result was received.jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js (9,3266)
    SignalR: webSockets reconnecting.jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js (9,3266)
    SignalR: Connecting to websocket endpoint 'longString'.jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js (9,3266)
    SignalR: Websocket opened.jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js (9,3266)
```

And as you can see, my **create** action works:

```
SignalR: Invoking discussionhub.Createjquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js (9,3266)
SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'DiscussionCreated' on hub 'DiscussionHub'.jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js (9,3266)
```

Can anyone spot the problem with my application? Because I'm not sure what the problem even could be.

Comment: Check the output of your ASP.NET app, there probably is an unhandled exception that is closing the websocket.

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari I checked the output of the GetAll and it returns the array with the complex object (Objects within the Object) nicely. And when running the create method the table on the "index" page updates with the newly created row. It also saves it in the Database table. But after refreshing the page manually it's all gone again and the GetAll() method fails.

Comment: When you refresh the page the websocket connection is forcibly reestablished, so it sound like the log you see is correct...

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari I fixed it. See my answer to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I've found a **solution**. And it turns out to be really easy.
Let met see if I can explain it a little bit. I probably need some help from other people to elaborate further as to *why* this was happening, but I've got a working solution so, here we go.

My application tried to return a very **complex** array with multiple objects through the `GetAll()` method in the Hub. And then I got the idea that SignalR just doesn't know how to handle this, so I needed to **simplify** things.

I decided to create a DTO (Data Transfer Object) for the Discussion class, so I created a new class `DiscussionDTO` and I just copied over the values I needed in my Index. In this case that was just `int ID` and `string Title`.

Then I went ahead and added **AutoMapper** to my project. Created a Map between Discussion and DiscussionDTO, initialized it and then edited my `getAll()` method inside the Hub to this:

```
        public IEnumerable<DiscussionDTO> GetAll()
    {

        var all = _ctx.Discussions.ToArray();

        var discussionDTO = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Discussion>, IEnumerable<DiscussionDTO>>(all);

        return discussionDTO;
    }
```

So now it returns only the values I really needed, and voila, the result is that I get a nice little IEnumerable array which passes to my Javascript and displays on the View.

```
-       discussionDTO   Count = 2   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<talkbooks.Models.DiscussionDTO> {System.Collections.Generic.List<talkbooks.Models.DiscussionDTO>}
-       [0] {talkbooks.Models.DiscussionDTO}    talkbooks.Models.DiscussionDTO
        ID  1   int
        Title   "A Game of Thrones" string
-       [1] {talkbooks.Models.DiscussionDTO}    talkbooks.Models.DiscussionDTO
        ID  6   int
        Title   "asb"   string
```

Now as to why the previous array was too complicated to send over SignalR, I really don't know. Please edit or add to my answer because I would like to know the reason for it and perhaps other people do too.

Comment: I have the suspicion that this is only a temporary fix, that the real problem lies somewhere else :/

Comment: Care to elaborate on your suspicion a little bit?